# I'm confused about my bootloader

Tags: grub2, uefi

Sometimes I reset my desktop and press <kbd>F2</kbd> and then `GRUB` loads up. But some other times I reset and press  <kbd>F2</kbd> and then the `Asus UEFI BIOS Utility` loads up.

I'm new to the  `Asus UEFI Bios utility` and have been diligently playing around with it. What setting causes the varying functionality I'm observing when I reset and press  <kbd>F2</kbd>?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you have grub as default, it probably is that it did not register f2 to get into system fast enough. Many UEFI have a fast boot setting (not Windows fast start up) which give essentially no time to press any keys. If cold booting then it may not use the fast boot? My Asus motherboard has settings for fast boot separate for each of cold boot & warm/reboot. And time delay to give time to press a key.

Answer (score 0):

It once happened to my and the problem was that my CMOS battery ran out of juice. 
It could be something else for you but this looks like a possible cause